# How to use a C++ lambda to convert a member function pointer to a normal function pointer for use as a callback

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have some code that needs a C function, but I want to instantiate a bunch of class instances and pass a member function from that class as the C function.  I need to capture N instances concurrently.  I'm hoping I can do it as a lambda.

Here's what the resulting function should look like (roughly):

```
// This is the code I want to interface with:

typedef void func(ParamClass param); // ParamClass is NOT my class

extern void notMyCode1(func funcArg); // Code I want to call, saves funcArg
extern void notMyCode2()  // uses saved funcArgs


// Here is the type of class I want to instantiate:

class MyClass {
   public:
       MyClass(int arg) : saveArg(arg) {}

       int saveArg;

   void myFunc(ParamClass param) {
       // uses saveArg and param to do the right action
   }

};

void useCase(void) {
   for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
       MyClass myInstance(Myclass(i)); // maybe need vector to hold these?
       notMyCode1(myInstance.myFunc); // this code is what I don't know how to write
    }
    notMyCode2();
}
```

Background.  The library I want to call is Google Benchmark.  notMyCode1 is their benchmark registration function.  notMyCode2 runs the benchmarks that were registered.  ParamClass is data their code passes into the benchmark.

Now, normally, one passes a simple C function to the registration code, one for each benchmark one wishes to run.  However, I want to run the same code over and over again parameterizing it by this number "i" and have each "i" treated as a separate benchmark.  So, I want to capture "i" in a class (or via a lambda, but something that yields me multiple 
C function pointers with the value of "i" bound in each one).  I tried making "i" a parameter to the benchmark and passing it in, but then the benchmark code treated "i" as something to sum over (and I want each "i" treated as a unique benchmark with a different parameter for the statistics to be calculated over).

This seems like something that ought to be simple to do, (it's just a closure) but I'm not that conversant with function pointers (or C++ lambdas).  If it were my code, I would just pass the class instance in, but it isn't.

I've seen examples that use static functions in the class, but I specifically want to capture the value of "i" and get multiple function pointers, each one capturing a different value of "i".

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/google/benchmark) you are not at all limited to C functions. You can set a [range](https://github.com/google/benchmark#passing-arguments) and [pass arbitrary arguments](https://github.com/google/benchmark#passing-arbitrary-arguments-to-a-benchmark) such as your class just fine.

Comment: @nwp member function pointers still aren't the same type of beast as regular function pointers (and they're not convertible to each other). If they handle them fine, then that is the best solution, but does the `BENCHMARK_CAPTURE` macro/function handle them correctly?

Comment: They don't need to handle it. You do it yourself. You write a benchmark function that takes as extra parameter the class and just calls the member function. Or it takes a pointer to the class and a pointer to member function and uses `std::invoke`. Since the function always takes a `benchmark::State& state` as the first parameter the chances of getting around having to write the benchmark function are slim.

Comment: Righto. Friday is real. My mind isn't at 100%

Comment: From further investigation.  It looks like if the called wants a C function, this isn't [easily] possible.  However, I found that the caller was wrapping the result in a class, so I defined my own class and substituted it.  It looks like they also have a version that accepts lambdas and not just C functions.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot.

A lambda only has a conversion to function pointer if it is stateless (i.e. there's no captures). To call a member function from a lambda, you need a pointer to an object with which to call the member function. This is captured, rendering the lambda object not convertible to a simple function pointer.

The only option you might have is to do the index parametrization at compile time using templates. Then you return to using simple static functions of a class template which can be passed as a C callback.